# Moving grid lines in \datavisualization

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I have a logarithmic graph with `\datavisualization` in a reduced graphical setting, so no axis around it. I got it set up nicely and the way I want it. Now I want to add some grid lines that are only around the actual path, i.e. ±3 x units at each power step. I can get that to work by hand, but it looks fugly and I would have to adjust the position for all 33 graphs by hand. My first idea was to use the intersections library, but I cannot grab the plot output as a path. `name path` throws an error unless I put it into the `style` of the plot, but then I cannot access it.

Since then, I have given up and decided just to `clip` the entire graph, only to learn that `datavisualization` ignores the `clip`.

My bare plot looks like:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization,intersections}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{China_GDPpP.csv}%Cut to keep it shorter
Year,Beijing
2014,99120
2010,71934
2009,65338
2008,62761
2005,45315
2000,23179
1995,12690
1990,4635
1985,2643
1980,1544
1978,1257
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization[
new Cartesian axis=x axis, x axis={attribute=Year},
new Cartesian axis= y axis, y axis={attribute=Beijing}, %call specific column in a multi-column file
x axis={scaling=1978 at 0cm and 2015 at 5cm, unit vector={(1pt,0)}},
y axis={logarithmic,scaling=1000 at 0cm and 100000 at 3cm,unit vector={(90:1pt)}}
visualize as line=GDPpP, GDPpP={style={color=blue}}]
data [set=GDPpP,read from file=data/China_GDPpP.csv];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Since I call different columns via `y axis={attribute={}}`, I have set up a second axis `u axis` that would then stay constant across all 33 graphs. This also contains a node at the beginning and end of the graph, indicating the `y axis` value at that point.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization,intersections}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{China_GDPpP.csv}%Cut to keep it shorter
Year,Beijing
2014,99120
2010,71934
2009,65338
2008,62761
2005,45315
2000,23179
1995,12690
1990,4635
1985,2643
1980,1544
1978,1257
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization[
new Cartesian axis=x axis, x axis={attribute=Year},
new Cartesian axis= y axis, y axis={attribute=Beijing}, %call specific column in a multi-column file
new Cartesian axis=u axis, u axis={attribute=help},
x axis={scaling=1978 at 0cm and 2015 at 5cm, unit vector={(1pt,0)}},
y axis={logarithmic,scaling=1000 at 0cm and 100000 at 3cm,unit vector={(0,1pt)}},
u axis={logarithmic,scaling=1000 at 0cm and 100000 at 3cm,unit vector={(90:1pt)}},
visualize as line=helplines,helplines={style={gray!30}},
visualize as line=mainhelplines,mainhelplines={style={gray!50}},
visualize as line=GDPpP, GDPpP={style={blue,name path=datacurve}}]
data [set=mainhelplines]{
Year, help
1979, 1000} %provide one data point to ensure the u axis is drawn
data [set=GDPpP,read from file=data/China_GDPpP.csv]
info{%
\path[name path=line1000] (visualization cs: Year=1978, help=1000) -- (visualization cs: Year=2015,help=1000);
\draw[name intersections={of=datacurve and line1000}] [shift={visualization cs: Year=-3,help=0}] (intersection-1) -- [shift={visualization cs: Year=+3,help=0}] (intersection-1);} %info allows accessing the visualization cs:
\draw [gray] (visualization cs: Year=1978,help=1000) node[left,font=\scriptsize]{1000} (visualization cs: Year=2015,help=100000) node[right,font=\scriptsize]{100000};}; %This works without problem, provided the single data point is there
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I run this code, it gives a `I don't know the path named 'data curve'` error.

Is there a way to make it work? In the end, the graphs will be combined with a coloured map and text all into one `tikzpicture`, so some `pstricks` is not a viable solution. The previous instance with linear data looks like this:
[image: Population as percentage of total]

Is there a solution that I am not seeing? I have scoured the manual several times but not found anything. My other idea would be to scale additional graphs up and below the plot line and `clip` the grid lines that way but I am hazy as to how to achieve that, if it works.